# Initramfs loads wrong keyboard language

Tags: initramfs

I cant enter my password for encrypted drive. 
After 5 minutes I see a busybox shell which shows wrong keyboard language.

I tried to rebuild initramfs from a livecd, but nothing changed.

Previous kernels have the same problem.

Comment: What release and flavor of Ubuntu are you talking about?, which kernel(s)?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04. 4.18.0-20, 4.18.0-17